# Selenium building internet explorer driver javascript error

Tags: javascript, selenium, internet-explorer, automated-tests

I have my selenium standalone server set up as running with the IEDriver as a parameter using the selenium-standalone start --drivers.ie.arch=ia32 configuration.

I'm getting the following error when I try to run my internet explorer selenium test:

```
index.js:673
    throw new Error('Do not know how to build driver: ' + browser
    ^

Error: Do not know how to build driver: IE; did you forget to call 
usingServer(url)?
```

Yet I have the correct server listed in my code:

```
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');

driver = await new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('IE').usingServer('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub').build();
```

I have also tried this:

```
let driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('internet explorer')
    .usingServer('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub')
    .build();
```

but neither of these work and I get the same error message...

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2 Just read this article, you are missing something. And run your IE tests under administrator for future.

```
driver = new webdriver.Builder().
   usingServer("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub").  
   withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.ie()).
   build();
```

It works for me.